# Show that a function is analytic on $D$ if it is analytic on $D$ cut by a line with Morera's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider problem II.3.11 from Freitag and Busam's Complex Analysis:

> Let $D \in \mathbb{C}$ be open, and $L \in \mathbb{C}$ be a line. If $f : D \to \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function, which is analytic at all points $z \in D$, $z \not\in L$, then $f$ is analytic on the whole $D$.

I would like guidance towards a solution using Morera's Theorem. Here is my attempt.

Because $D$ is open, there exists an open disk $U$ centered around $z \in D, L$. We wish to show that for every triangular path $\alpha$ contained in $U$,
$$\int_{\alpha} f(\zeta) = 0.$$
If $\alpha$ does not contain any points in $L$, then we are done by applying Cauchy's integral theorem on one of the pieces of $U \setminus L$.

But I think we can't use Cauchy's Integral Theorem if $L$ intersects $\alpha$, so I am unsure how to continue. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that some trickery is needed to handle triangles that touch or cross the line. I'll illustrate some techniques for handling such triangles through some examples. I'll leave the general case to you.

In all my examples, $D$ is the whole complex plane, and $L$ is the real axis in the complex plane.

**Example 1: A corner touches the line.**

Suppose $\alpha$ is the triangle $$\alpha = [0, 1 + i , i].$$

Consider the three triangles  $$\alpha_1 = [0, \delta(1+i), \delta i],$$ $$\alpha_2 = [\delta i, \delta(1+i), 1 + i],$$
$$\alpha_3 = [\delta i, 1 + i, i].$$

Here, $\delta$ is positive number less than $1$.

The integral of $f$ along $\alpha$ is equal to the sum of the integrals of $f$ along $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$.

$\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$ don't intersect the line $L = \mathbb R$, so we can safely apply Cauchy's theorem to say that $\oint_{\alpha_2} f = \oint_{\alpha_3} f = 0$.

$\alpha_1$ is a little tricky because the corner at $0$ lies on $L$. However, we can show that $\oint_{\alpha_1} f \to 0$ in the limit $\delta \to 0$. Indeed, $f$ is bounded on the set $S = \{x + iy: x\in [0, 1], y \in [0, 1] \}$, since $f$ is continuous and $S$ is compact. So let $M$ be a number such that $|f(z)| < M$ for all $z \in S$. For all choices of $\delta$, $\alpha_1$ lies inside $S$, so $|f| < M$ along $\alpha_1$. Furthermore, for any $\epsilon > 0$, then the length of $\alpha_1$ is less than $(2 + \sqrt{2}) \epsilon$, provided that $\delta < \epsilon$. Thus, if $\delta < \epsilon$, then $|\oint_{\alpha_1} f| < M \times (2 + \sqrt{2})\epsilon $.

Thus we have shown that $\oint_{\alpha} f$ is the equal to a quantity that tends to zero in the limit $\delta \to 0$, plus a quantity that is zero for all $\delta$, plus another quantity that is zero for all $\delta$. So $\oint_{\alpha} f$ must be zero.

**Example 2: An edge runs along the line.**

Suppose $\alpha$ is the triangle $$ \alpha = [0, 1, i].$$

Consider the two polygonal paths
$$\alpha_1 = [\delta i, 1 + \delta i, i],$$
$$\alpha_2 = [0, 1, 1 + \delta i, \delta i].$$

$\alpha_1$ is a triangle, and $\alpha_2$ is a rectangle.

The integral of $f$ along $\alpha$ is equal to sum of the integrals along $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$. The integral along $\alpha_1$ vanishes by Cauchy's theorem, but $\alpha_2$ is problematic because the edge $[0, 1]$ runs along the line $L = \mathbb R$.

To deal with $\alpha_2$, we can argue as follows. $f$ is continuous on set $S = \{x + iy: x\in [0, 1], y \in [0, 1] \}$. The set $S$ is compact. So $f$ is in fact *uniformly* continuous on $S$. So for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta ' > 0$ such that for all $\delta < \delta'$, we have
$ |f(x + i\delta) - f(x)| < \epsilon$
for all $x \in [0, 1]$.

Using this observation, we can argue that $\oint_{\alpha_2} f \to 0$ in the limit $\delta \to 0$: the integrals along the top and bottom edges of the $\alpha_2$ cancel in this limit by our uniform continuity observation above.

**Example 3: The triangle crosses the line.**

Suppose $\alpha$ is the triangle $$\alpha = [-i, 2 + i , i].$$

Consider the three triangles  $$\alpha_1 = [-i, 1, 0],$$ $$\alpha_2 = [0, 1, 2 + i],$$
$$\alpha_3 = [0, 2 + i, i].$$

The integral along $\alpha$ is equal to the sums of the integrals along $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$.

$\alpha_3$ is a triangle with a corner that touches the line $L = \mathbb R$, whereas $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are triangles that have an edge that runs along the line $L = \mathbb R$. So they are handled by the logic in examples 1 and 2.